# Error while installing ruby gems(Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to install ruby hacker gems but its giving me an error
The error says-
'Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options'

My ruby version currently installed is
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

gems version is
3.2.5

here is the whole error

```
ERROR:  Error installing hacker-gems:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5/ext/tiny_tds
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby -r ./siteconf20210802-4029-18iz6u.rb extconf.rb
looking for freetds headers in the following directories:
 - /opt/local/include
 - /opt/local/include/freetds
 - /usr/local/include
 - /usr/local/include/freetds
looking for freetds library in the following directories:
 - /opt/local/lib
 - /opt/local/lib/freetds
 - /usr/local/lib
 - /usr/local/lib/freetds
checking for sybfront.h... no
checking for sybdb.h... no
checking for tdsdbopen() in -lsybdb... no
checking for dbanydatecrack() in -lsybdb... no
Failed! Do you have FreeTDS 0.95.80 or higher installed?
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.7
    --help
    --with-freetds-dir
    --without-freetds-dir
    --with-freetds-include
    --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include
    --with-freetds-lib
    --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/lib
    --with-sybdb-dir
    --without-sybdb-dir
    --with-sybdb-include
    --without-sybdb-include=${sybdb-dir}/include
    --with-sybdb-lib
    --without-sybdb-lib=${sybdb-dir}/lib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/tiny_tds-2.1.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/tiny_tds-2.1.5/gem_make.out
```

I tried installing various dependencies as well as scouring through the web but to no avail
What am i missing?

Comment: Was one of the dependencies you installed “FreeTDS 0.95.80 or higher“?

Comment: Yes @rmlockerd i immediately checked and a higher version was installed

Comment: Where are the freetds libs/headers installed? Somewhere other than `/opt/local/...` or `/usr/local/...`? If so, you will probably need to install the `tiny_tds` gem separately, specifying build switches to tell it where to find the includes/libs.

Comment: Look at the `mkmf.log` file noted in the error output. `cat /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/tiny_tds-2.1.5/mkmf.log` should tell you which headers you're missing

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error installing the `ruby-dev`

Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`